# How to duplicate an already initialised map in openlayers 3

Tags: mapping, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

How can i duplicate an already initialised map state?
I would like to save the hassle of re-initialising the same map then copying the layers over.

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the map object on different  tags just by changing the target div when you want to use it on different pages.

```
    map.setTarget('map-holder');
```

If you want to display both maps at the same time then you can try this example 
https://openlayersbook.github.io/ch03-charting-the-map-class/example-05.html.

One map cannot have two targets at the same time as far as I know. Hope that helps.